# Scala Presentation Compiler and IntelliJ

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, intellij-idea

The following definition...

```
object Category {
  def fCat = new Category[Function1] {
    def compose[A, B, C](f: (B) => C)(g: (A) => B) = { a: A => f(g(a)) }
  }
}
```

... is valid if `Category` is defined as:

```
trait Category[~>[_, _]] {
  def compose[A, B, C](f: ~>[B, C])(g: ~>[A, B]): ~>[A, C]
}
```

... but not when infixing the type constructor:

```
  def compose[A, B, C](f: B ~> C)(g: A ~> B): A ~> C
```

Here IntelliJ complains that member compose is not defined in `fCat`.

Is this a limitation of the Presentation Compiler? IntelliJ's Scala plugin? Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an IntelliJ bug; it has its own presentation compiler.

I've reported it here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4179